# No connected devices in android studio logcat "giraffe"

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating android studio to latest version "giraffe" logcat is unable to find any connected devices. However adb is showing devices physical and virtual both. Even i can install apps to virtual and physical devices but logcat is unbale to find any device and thus showing no logs. what i have tried so far.

1. Adb kill-server and restarting again.
2. Removing physical devices and plug in again.
3. Creating new virtual device
4. Restarting android studio
5. Updating build tools
6. Re-installing android studio
7. removing .idea and .gradle and rebuilding again.
8. Invalidate cache and restart
9. Restarting PC.

None of these work. Any help ?

[image]

Comment: What does `adb devices` command say, when you run it on the terminal? @Imran

Comment: @ASMSayem 
Displays the connected devices. Here is output
C:\Users> adb devices
List of devices attached
R9JR603M8RW     device

Comment: Have you tried to close the logcat window with the top right x button , and press the right side + icon for a brand new window?

Comment: @ImranAli can you check if your `adb.exe` is in the write path? Can you please find it and share it's path and the `platform-tools` path as well?

Comment: its in right path
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

Comment: `Tools` -> `SDK Manager` -> `SDK Tools` -> `Android SDK Platform-Tools` latest version installed? `File` -> `Settings` -> `Plugins` no updates / issues? Under `user/.android` are stored caches of virtual devices. Already cleaned? `AppData/Local/Google/AndroidStudio...` already tried to remove?

Comment: @ImranAli are you having multiple installations of Android studio? I.e. stable, beta & canary versions? Which Os are you using? This kind of issue requires broad vision to pinpoint the exact problem.

Comment: Yes I have two version installed on my laptop. Complete logs available here on google issue tracker. 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/297733246